# Fixing calculator function code that returns incorrect numerical value in Python?

Tags: python, math, calculator

I'm attempting to write a simple 4-function calculator program in Python, and I ran into an issue with the output. I can return the correct values for addition, but not any other function. My code looks like this:

```
def binop(expression):
    """expression = math expression"""
    if expression.find("+") != -1:
        operator = expression.find("+")
        num1 = int(expression[0:operator])
        num2 = int(expression[operator + 1: -1])
        return num1 + num2
    elif expression.find("-") != -1:
        operator = expression.find("-")
        num1 = int(expression[0:operator])
        num2 = int(expression[operator + 1: -1])
        return num1 - num2
    elif expression.find("/") != -1:
        operator = expression.find("/")
        num1 = int(expression[0:operator])
        num2 = int(expression[operator + 1: -1])
        return num1 / num2
    elif expression.find("*") != -1:
        operator = expression.find("*")
        num1 = int(expression[0:operator])
        num2 = int(expression[operator + 1: -1])
        return num1 * num2
```

But it returns incorrect values for subtraction, multiplication, and division. The addition is fine.

Any suggestions? I'm not allowed to import or use any eval or compile functions.

Answer (score 1):

You are using slicing operation incorrectly for `num2`.

The general syntax for slicing is `"a[start:stop:step]"` where

- ***start*** An integer number specifying at which position to
  start the slicing. Default is 0
- ***end*** An integer number specifying at which position to end the slicing
- ***step***    An integer number specifying the step of the slicing.
  Default is 1

Consider the expression `expression = "10/20"`, here index of operator is `2` and when you call `expression[operator + 1: -1]` this will return `2` not `20` as required.

So you have to call `expression[operator + 1:]` so that it will return `20`.
Here is the correct code:

```
def binop(expression):
    """expression = math expression"""
    if expression.find("+") != -1:
        operator = expression.find("+")
        num1 = int(expression[0:operator])
        num2 = int(expression[operator + 1:])
        return num1 + num2
    elif expression.find("-") != -1:
        operator = expression.find("-")
        num1 = int(expression[0:operator])
        num2 = int(expression[operator + 1:])
        return num1 - num2
    elif expression.find("/") != -1:
        operator = expression.find("/")
        num1 = int(expression[0:operator])
        num2 = int(expression[operator + 1:])
        return num1 / num2
    elif expression.find("*") != -1:
        operator = expression.find("*")
        num1 = int(expression[0:operator])
        num2 = int(expression[operator + 1:])
        return num1 * num2
```